# plotting a function f against a parameter that f depends on

Tags: python

I have a system of ODEs

$\begin{cases}S^\prime =lambda-beta S I/N -muS\
I^\prime=beta S I/N-muI\end{case}$

I want to plot I against R1=beta/mu

I defined a function

```
def f(y,t,Lambda,beta,mu):
    y=S,I
    ds_dt=lambda-beta S I/N -muS
    dI_dt=beta S I/N-muI
    
   return([ds_dt,dI_dt])
```

Then I set some initial conditions

```
S0=30
I0=302
muh=0.4
Lambda=0.2
beta=0.7
```

```
t=numpy.linspace(1,100,200)

Solution=scipy.integrate,odeint(f,[ds_dt,dI_dt],t,args=(Lambda,mu,beta))
solution=numpy.array(solution)
```

With this, I am able to plot I against t

```
plt,plot(t,solution[:,0]
```

What I want to do next is to plot I against R, where R=beta/mu, that is the bifurcation diagram.

How can I create the R array?

Comment: Just substitute it into your existing line = `plt.plot(beta/mu,solution[:,0])`

Comment: @mkrieger My problem is that I am struggling to create an array (or a set of point) representing R. R=beta/mu, I tried defining it with the function but I cannot figure how I can get points for R such that R=beta/mu

Comment: @ciaran that did now work, it says that x and y must have same first dimension. I think that this is because solution[:,0] is a set of point while beta/mu is just one number. I want to create a slider for R=beta/mu, plot I against R and see how I behaves as R is varied